# Using Core Plot, how can I draw a bar chart in all four quadrants of the plot space?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

Using the Core Plot framework and its CPGraphHostingView, I have drawn a bar chart in the first quadrant of an X / Y plot.

I want to plot the bar chart in the second, third, and fourth quadrant of this plot.  How can I do that?

Comment: What is CPGraphHostingView... What SDK are you reffering to?

Comment: I've edited your question to make it a little clearer, but I'm still not sure what you want to do.  Am I right in thinking that you can draw a bar chart that appears in the positive X and Y quadrant, but you want the chart to also have some values appear in the negative X and Y axes?  Why not just provide negative X and Y values to the chart?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do here, but if what you want is four independent bar charts, you are going to need one CPGraphHostingView for each one of them, since a CPGraphHostingView holds only one CPXYGraph.